# Python. Требуется помощь с корректным добавлением в список

Tags: python, список

Здравствуйте! Требуется помощь:`введите сюда код`

```
list = ['0', '1']
res = []

def a(a):
    list[0] = a
    return list

def x():
    for i in range(5):
        a(i)
        print(a(i))
        res.append(a(i))
    print(res)
```

Необходимо чтоб список res содержал в финале список возможных вариантов списка list, чего почему-то не происходит, хотя на принте a(i) все выглядит корректно. Не пойму в чем дело. Как здесь нужно правильно поместить значения в список res, чтоб в финале получить [[0, '1'], [1, '1'], [2, '1'], [3, '1'], [4, '1']]?

Так, с этим вопросом вроде разобрались, решением было определять список внутри функции. А если задача усложнилась, и с этим списком надо работать сразу 2ум функциям? тут без глобальной переменной не обойтись ведь, а это снова возвращает на начало. Вот исправленный по замечаниям код и новая задача)

```
lst = ['0', '1']

def a(one):
    lst[0] = one
    return lst

def b(two):
    lst[1] = two
    return lst

def x():
    rng = range(5)
    res = []
    for i in rng:
        a(i)
        for j in rng:
            b(j)
            res.append(lst)
    print(res)
x()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас list определена за пределами функции a.

Соответственно, каждый раз, когда вы внутри функции 'a' вы манипулируете переменной list, то это каждый раз тот же самый список. Чтобы каждый раз заново создавался отдельный список, вам нужно определять его внутри функции:

```
res = []

def a(a):
    list = ['0', '1']
    list[0] = a
    return list

def x():
    for i in range(5):
        a(i)
        print(a(i))
        res.append(a(i))
    print(res)
```

Ну и по мелочам:

1. list - это зарезервированное ключевое слово, не стоит его использовать в качестве имени переменной. Если бы программа была чуть больше и сложнее, вы с большой вероятностью получили бы из-за этого проблемы. Для обозначения некоего безымянного списка можно использовать имя "lst" или "list_".
2. Вот эта строка вообще "чудесна":

   def a(a):

Не используйте одно и то же имя для разных сущностей - это очень запутывает.

3. Ну и то, что вы делаете с res - это не очень хорошо. Старайтесь не использовать глобальные переменные. В хорошем коде все переменные, которые вы изменяете внутри функции (не метода), должны быть созданы внутри этой функции.

Хороший программист для вашей задачи создал бы объект res, и сделал функцию x в качестве метода этого объекта.

```
class Res(list):

    def x(self):
        for i in range(5):
            a(i)
            print(self)
            self.append(a(i))
        print(self)


def a(a):
    list = ['0', '1']
    list[0] = a
    return list


res = Res()
res.x()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Блин постоянно поражаюсь, как же все просто было, когда нахожу ответ)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый комментарий. На самом деле это не весь код, это очень упрощенный кусок большого скрипта, с измененными названиями переменных, без всяких классов и тд., здесь мне важно было понять принцип. Хотелось бы получить еще ответ на такой вопрос, что делать, если со списком list нужно работать одновременно нескольким функциям, и записывать все туда же - в многострадальный res? например функция b, которая меняла бы list[1]?

Comment: У класса может быть много методов.

Answer (score 2):

подобные списки создаются примерно так

```
[[i, 1] for i in range(5)]
```